# How to make swipe ball throw mechanics in godot in 3d

Tags: 3d, swipe, godot, pokemon-go

I have made this script which is working fine but in reverse direction.

```
extends KinematicBody

var velocity = Vector3.ZERO
var touch_pos

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if event.pressed:
            # Store touch position
            touch_pos = Vector3(event.position.x, event.position.y, 0)
        else:
            # Calculate swipe direction
            var swipe_dir = Vector3(event.position.x, event.position.y, 0) - touch_pos
            # Set ball velocity
            velocity = -swipe_dir.normalized() * 10

func _physics_process(delta):
    # Update ball position
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

I solved the problem of revrse swipe i.e, firstly the ball was moving opposite direction of my swipe, if I swipe down to up so it goes down I solved it by using `velocity = -swipe_dir.normalized() * 10` by placing negative sign but my original problem of reverse throwing means it is getting swipe towards my screen or say camera. **In simple words I want to make it go in forward direction but it is going in backward direction and please don't get confused with -swipe_dir.normalized() * 10**.

Thanks

Comment: Those are different coordinate systems: the input is in screen coordinates, and the velocity is in world coordinates. So having the camera oriented in a different way will result in different apparent behavior. So you will need some kind of conversion. With that said, I do not know what behavior is desirable. *Yes, I know you want it reversed from what you have, if that is what you are going to tell me, you didn't understand what I said. Moving the camera might give you a better grasp of what is going on*.